# Is there a bug in sublimetext 3 autoprefixer?

Tags: css, sublimetext3, autoprefixer

I have been using sublimetext3 for doing webpages. There is a plugin called autoprefixer which I installed and has been working. After upgrading to windows 10 I notice a strange bug in autoprefixer.

It works when I run it, but doesn't put in any safari vendor code.
For instance check out the following code

```
.flexjustify_space {
        justify-content: space-between;
}
.equalHW {
        flex: 1;
}
.equalHWdetails {
        flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

After I run sublimetext3 autoprefixer I get this

```
.flexjustify_space {
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: -between;
}space
.equalHW {
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
}
.equalHWdetails {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
            flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

You will notice there are no Safari vender codes
eg

```
display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
```

Is this a bug in Sublimetext3 autoprefixer, or do I have to update something?
Can somebody who uses sublimetext3 and autoprefixer help me out?

Comment: The plugin was just updated a day ago, so it's very possible there is a bug. I would suggest opening an [issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer/issues) on Github and explaining the situation there.

Comment: Thanks Matt I have created a github account to let them know about the issue.